# Verify if the deleteObject has actually deleted the object in AWS S3 Java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have the following method, which deletes a file from AWS S3 Bucket, however,

- there is no exception thrown if the file doesn't exist
- there is no success code or flag to see if the file has been deleted successfully

is there any workaround to deal with this situation.

```
@Override
public void deleteFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        this.client.deleteObject(builder ->
                builder
                        .bucket(this.bucketName).key(fileName)
                        .build());
    } catch (S3Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your request succeeded then your object is deleted. Note, that due to eventual consistency, the object is not guaranteed to disappear immediately. You need to check on the HTTP status code.

```
AmazonS3 as3 = new AmazonS3();
Status myStatus = as3.DeleteObject(<fill in paramters here>);
if (myStatus.Code >= 200 && myStatus.Code < 300)
{
  // Success
}
else
{
  // Delete Failed

  // Handle specific Error Codes below
  if (myStatus.Description == "AllAccessDisabled")
  {
    // Do something
  }

  if (myStatus.Description == "NoSuchKey")
  {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Also, there is an api available to check if the Object exists in S3
doesObjectExist

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#doesObjectExist-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: Also note: "If attempting to delete an object that does not exist, Amazon S3 returns a success message instead of an error message."